# How to fill ApplIdentityData in MQ message

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have a message queue and use it from java code via `MQQueueConnectionFactory`.
I have a userid/password and need to set `ApplIdentityData` field, how to do it correctly (via properties, something else?)?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of WMQ Java classes are you using?  This was possible in v6 and rather easy in v7.0 but the method to do it differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation we solved this issue:

```
    queue.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
    queue.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_READ_ENABLED, true);
    queue.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_MESSAGE_CONTEXT, WMQConstants.WMQ_MDCTX_SET_ALL_CONTEXT);
    ...
    message.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MQMD_APPLIDENTITYDATA, "....");
```